# Are compound statements required with if conditions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: if-statement, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a statement in MVC which I think looks better without the compound braces, but I cannot get it to work. The statement, when it works, is this:

```
<td>
    @if (SessionState.HasInvitations)
    {
        <a href='@ApplicationState.FormatInviteURL(item)'>@item.InviteNumber</a>
    }
    else
    {
        @item.InviteNumber
    }
</td>
```

I would like to remove the braces, but the following does not work...

```
<td>
    @if (SessionState.HasInvitations)
        <a href='@ApplicationState.FormatInviteURL(item)'>@item.InviteNumber</a>
    else
        @item.InviteNumber
</td>
```

Is there a way to do this which I'm simply missing or am I doomed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you delete braces only the if code block will be executed and your  tag will be rendered, I recommend using braces for clean code but if you want do this inline you can

```
@SessionState.HasInvitations?<a href='@ApplicationState.FormatInviteURL(item)'>@item.InviteNumber</a>:@item.InviteNumber
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right... With braces is actually more readable. Thanks :)